# MySQL query takes 20+ seconds?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've collected diagnostics, but I'm unsure why its happening. I can't see any majorly large lock times, or a huge amount of sub queries being ran accidentally.

Query:

```
SELECT message, level, logged_at FROM application_logs
 WHERE application_id = 5 AND
       message NOT LIKE '(build)%' AND
       logged_at >= ( 
           SELECT launched_at 
           FROM application_sessions 
           WHERE application_id = 5 
           ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
        ) 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500;
```

I run this query 1 time per user connected to the site. Its currently running at a rate of around 6/second and with it taking as long as it is, that's a big issue.

The tables `application_logs` is around 2.5 million rows and `application_sessions` about 20k rows. I should probably be purging application_logs < 7 days or something.

With EXPLAIN:
It's still running, bare with

Slow query log:

```
 SELECT message, level, logged_at 
 FROM application_logs 
 WHERE application_id = 9 AND message NOT LIKE '(build)%' 
 AND logged_at >= (
   SELECT launched_at 
   FROM application_sessions 
   WHERE application_id = 9 
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
   ) 
 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

> User@Host: remote[remote] @  [**************] Thread_id: 14180
> Schema: ****  QC_hit: No Query_time: 21.056101  Lock_time: 0.000102
> Rows_sent: 19  Rows_examined: 233153 Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent:
> 3421

```
SET timestamp=1681832466;
SELECT message, level, logged_at 
FROM application_logs 
WHERE application_id = 9 AND message NOT LIKE '(build)%' 
AND logged_at >= (
    SELECT launched_at 
    FROM application_sessions 
    WHERE application_id = 9 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
) ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: First stop is usually `EXPLAIN`. Second stop is checking index coverage. Third step is looking at how things like your "build" prefix can be broken out into a column easy to match on. You'll also want to try a `JOIN` instead of a subquery.

Comment: This is just off the top, but it seems like if you had logs associated with a particular "launch" directly it'd be trivial to select rows related to any given launch.

Comment: please do edit your question to show (as text, not images) the explain output and `show create table application_logs;` and `show create table application_sessions;` and `select version();`

Answer (score 0):

The query on your `application_logs` table looks like this, with the WHERE clauses reordered. The order of the clauses you write in your query makes no difference to performance; I have re-ordered them simply to help explain things.

```sql
SELECT message, level, logged_at 
  FROM application_logs 
 WHERE application_id = 9           -- equality matches first
   AND logged_at >= something       -- a single range match second
   AND message NOT LIKE '(build)%'  -- miscellaneous matches third
 ORDER BY id DESC                   -- ordering
 LIMIT 100
```

You can use a [multicolumn](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) [covering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) index on that table to accelerate this query.

```sql
ALTER TABLE application_logs CREATE INDEX app_logged_message_id
        (application_id, logged_at, message, id DESC);
```

Using a BTREE index is like accessing a sorted list of the rows in the table. Your query uses this index as follows.

1. It random-accesses the index to the first row with with the desired `application_id` and the first `logged_at` value that's larger than the desired starting point (from your subquery).
2. It then accesses the *index* (not the *table*) sequentially looking for rows that match your `message NOT LIKE` clause.
3. It pulls out the `id` values in the order you want and stops scanning when it hits your limit.

Try it; it will probably help.

With similar logic, your subquery can benefit from this index.

```sql
ALTER TABLE application_sessions CREATE INDEX app_id_launched
        (application_id, id DESC, launched_at);
```

The server can random-access the index to the row it needs and retrieve the `launched_at` column for that row, really quickly.

To get the information you need to understand this sort of thing, [prefix your query with `EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html). Then [examine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.htm) the EXPLAIN output.

[Read this for a more thorough explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Comment: The proposed index has two columns with range predicates preceding the sort column in the index definition. Is that index still able to provide the requested sort (3rd item)? I wasn't able to find details on that in the final link

Comment: The docs and EXPLAIN output aren't helpful on that precise topic, as you have discovered.  You can test it. If you use InnoDB and the `id` column is the primary key, you can omit that column: PKs are implicitly part of every index in InnoDB. The covering index will still help.